# How do I disable the arrow keys in insert mode?

Tags: vim

I have the following lines in my .vimrc, which I thought would be more than sufficient:

```
nnoremap <left> <nop>
nnoremap <right> <nop>
nnoremap <up> <nop>
nnoremap <down> <nop>

inoremap <left> <nop>
inoremap <right> <nop>
inoremap <up> <nop>
inoremap <down> <nop>
```

The arrow keys don't do anything (as expected) in normal mode, but continue to function in insert mode. I've also tried `imap` and that doesn't work either. Querying the mapping with `inoremap <left>` confirms that the binding isn't getting overwritten by something else. I'm not sure what's going on.

As one last test, I started up vim with no vimrc with `vim -u NONE`, then only ran the mappings. If I enter insert mode and hit an arrow key now, it inserts the letters A, B, C or D on a new line where my cursor is, which is completely not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 9):

Based on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140107033737/http://www.messaliberty.com/2009/01/how-to-disable-the-arrow-keys-in-vi-or-vim/), you can do it with the following mappings.

```
 noremap  <Up> ""
 noremap! <Up> <Esc>
 noremap  <Down> ""
 noremap! <Down> <Esc>
 noremap  <Left> ""
 noremap! <Left> <Esc>
 noremap  <Right> ""
 noremap! <Right> <Esc>
```

I tested them and they work, but I do not currently understand why this magic works.

In particular, I am not sure why it is necessary to map *twice*, but it should be effective for solving your problem.

Comment: There are several `:help map-modes`, the `:map` and `:map!` variants both bundle several of them; together, they cover _all_ modes.

Answer (score 1):

That insertion of A B C D rings a bell. You seem to have the problem described in [Fix broken arrow key navigation in insert mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_broken_arrow_key_navigation_in_insert_mode) and [Fix arrow keys that display A B C D on remote shell](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell), and possibly a workaround implemented.

That interferes with the `:imap`s to `<Nop>`.